# Accuracy assessment resulting values as strings in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, accuracy-assessment

I am trying to create a panel that shows a value on the map. The value should show the resulting value of an accuracy assessment(for instance: `ConfusionMatrix.accuracy()`). I am using the following piece of code:

```js
var acc_val= ee.String(trainAccuracy.accuracy())

var legendTitle = ui.Label({
  value: 'Overall Accuracy:'+  acc_val , 
  style: {
    fontSize: '18px',
    margin: '0 0 4px 0',
    padding: '0'
    }
});
Map.add(panel);
panel.add(legendTitle);
```

where `acc_val` should be a number or string, but it shows a long list of characters.

This is what I get:

[image: what I get:]

This is what I expect:

[image: What I expect:]

The code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1a480fa4d380388b2f64276809b9f59f).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this because you do client-side concatenation on `acc_val`, which is a server-side object. Read [Client vs. Server](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server) in the Earth Engine docs for an explanation. You can convert `acc_val` to a client-side object with `evaluate()`:

```
var acc_val = ee.String(trainAccuracy.accuracy()) // Server-side object

acc_val.evaluate(function(value) { // Turn acc_val into client-side object
  var legendTitle = ui.Label({
    value: 'Overall Accuracy: ' + value,
    style: {
      fontSize: '18px',
      margin: '0 0 4px 0',
      padding: '0'
    }
  });
  Map.add(panel);
  panel.add(legendTitle);
})
```